# Unable to implement api key authentication passport NestJS

Tags: nestjs, passport.js

I'm trying here to implement a token-based authentication using the passport-headerapikey library.

This is what I've tried so far, and for some reason I have a 500 server error popping from somewhere I couldn't find.

This is the structure of my authentication system (I also have a JWT-token based strategy in parallel on my graphQL queries).

**app.module**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(AuthMiddleware).forRoutes('/datasource/:id');
  }
}
```

**auth.module**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    DatasourceTokenStrategy,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**datasourceToken.strategy**

```
@Injectable()
export class DatasourceTokenStrategy extends PassportStrategy(
  HeaderAPIKeyStrategy,
  'datasourceToken',
) {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super(
      { header: 'datasourceToken', prefix: '' },
      true,
      (apikey, done, req) => {
        const checkKey = authService.validateDatasourceToken(apikey);
        if (!checkKey) {
          return done(false);
        }
        return done(true);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**authMiddleware.strategy**

```
import {
  Injectable,
  NestMiddleware,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import * as passport from 'passport';
@Injectable()
export class AuthMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
    passport.authenticate(
      'datasourceToken',
      { session: false, failureRedirect: '/api/unauthorized' },
      (value) => {
        if (value) {
          next();
        } else {
          throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
      },
    )(req, res, next);
  }
}
```

This is the error thrown when testing the endpoint with Jest:
[image]

[image]

When running my debug mode, I can see that the datasourceToken strategy is ok (I can retrieve the datasourceToken properly and validate it), but I think the problem is happening after my auth middleware..

Thanks guys for your insights

Answer (score 0):

The function "done()" takes 3 arguments.

```
done(error, user, info)
```

You need to pass null as the first argument to let passport know that there was no error while authenticating.

```
done(null, true)
```